# Modern CMS for Ruby on Rails

Tags: open-source, library, cms, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Is there any recommendable modern CMS (-engine) for Ruby on Rails?

It should *not* be some 'external' or API-CMS like Contentful but rather something that's *fully integrated* but still has a modern backend.

It seems that Alchemy CMS, [Spina](https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina), [Camaleon](https://github.com/owen2345/camaleon-cms), [Fae CMS](https://github.com/wearefine/fae), [Publify](https://github.com/publify/publify), Locomotive CMS (is it worth to have MongoDB as a dependency?), [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) and [Casein](https://github.com/russellquinn/casein) are actively developed at the moment. But are they good? I didn't try any of them.

I also found pavecms.com which seems to have a WYSIWYG backend but the company wasn't responsive via the contact form and I didn't find anything about licensing/pricing anyway.

Does anyone has experience and advice?

What are good factors to watch out when looking for a CMS engine?

Comment: I've looked for an CMS for rails to and the ones you mention are in my opinion outdated or very minimal. I don't think people spend much time on building an good CMS in rails because when you say CMS I think the most people will think about wordpress. If you want a good CMS in rails I would say build your own.

Comment: I choosed Alchemy CMS. I don't like the backend UI, but other than that it is really good. The architecture is well designed and I would go for it again.